# Return value rather than boolean using Julia

Tags: matrix, julia, unary-operator

I would like to do this (from matlab):

```
dists = abs(points(3,(I(1,:)>0)&(I(1,:)<Im_w)&(I(2,:)>0)&(I(2,:)<Im_h)) - t(3))
```

in Julia - where I is a 3x55 matrix.

I get that its abs(points[3,....]-t(3)). I want it to return just the values that satisfy the criteria, the first being:

```
I[1,:] .> 0
```

But all I get is the boolean out, as the documentation suggests is going to happen. What I cant get is a new mx with all the values that are > 0..

This is as close to it as I have:
http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/athena/software/julia_v0.3/www/

```
v(x) = (println(x); x)

julia> v(1) < v(2) <= v(3)
```

But they say do not use print.. This is a simple question I know.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you want this `J = I[1, I[1,:].>0]`.

Comment: take a look at julia's [array indexing](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/arrays/#indexing), it can take a boolean vector.

Comment: I think if you want to translate `points(3,(I(1,:)>0)&(I(1,:)<Im_w)&(I(2,:)>0)&(I(2,:)<Im_h))` from matlab to julia the nearest statement is `points[3,(I[1,:].>0)&(I[1,:].<Im_w)&(I[2,:].>0)&(I[2,:].<Im_h)]`

Comment: Thank you @RezaAfzalan that did the trick, and GnumicKey that area of the docs really helped - much appreciated. How do I mark as answer?

Comment: I wrote a community wiki answer, so you can mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a copy of an array with only selected values in Julia-lang:

```
J = I[1, I[1,:].>0]
```

and [here](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/arrays/#indexing) is the related documentation about array indexing.
But to translate
`points(3,(I(1,:)>0)&(I(1,:)<Im_w)&(I(2,:)>0)&(I(2,:)<Im_h))`
from matlab to Julia the nearest statement is:
`points[3,(I[1,:].>0)&(I[1,:].<Im_w)&(I[2,:].>0)&(I[2,:].<Im_h)]`

Comment: IMHO, that's completely unreadable (EDIT: in both Matlab and Julia): it's totally unclear what it's trying to do. It's also liable to be slow in Julia. It would probably be more natural just to use some kind of `if` to control where a certain expression is evaulated.